# Computer Algebra System Accessible in Javascript

Tags: open-source, javascript, algebra, computer-algebra-systems

Does anyone know of a good Open Source CAS Library that is easily accessible in JavaScript. It doesn't have to be extremely powerful. The core functionality I'm looking for is the simplification of algebraic expressions.

All answers are helpful (Sorry this is my first time on SO).

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: I haven't used this personally, but [LissaJS](https://github.com/numbas/LissaJS) may help. It's actually a spin-off of [NUMBAS e-assessment system](https://github.com/numbas/Numbas).

Comment: thanks @AlexanderKonovalov I'll have a look at it

Comment: I don't agree with this closing off of this topic.  The question was related to programming, it was a direct answerable question, not a vague question, and I gave a simple direct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the package Coffeequate, the site is located here http://matthewja.com/Coffeequate/.